# One vector with multiple iterators in multithreaded lock free application

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stl, lock-free

I have the following functionality at the c++ application:

1. There is a one preallocated std::vector of fixed length
2. 1st thread do a lookups through the vector (just lookups of the elements, matching some pattern)
3. 2nd thread sometimes updates elements of the vector (just updates, it does not remove elements)
4. 3rd thread updates vector elements as well (condition, when it overlaps with 2nd thread is **absolutely excluded**)

Each thread uses own iterator for iterating through vector elements. It means, one iterator can be moved by one thread only.

The question is: is this thread-safe, to simultaneously iterate through the std::vector, using multiple threads, which, it turn, do it through dedicated iterators (each tread use own iterator for this purpose).

What I am afraid of, is that somewhere deep inside in STL, it may cause some malfunction (maybe I am paranoid). I tested this approach and it seems working, however would like to get some feedback from experts.

Comment: Besides reading/writing race conditions you are safe.

Comment: Some STL implementations (especially in debug builds) have checks to make sure iterators are used correctly (e.g., that an invalid iterator is not used).  It's easy to imagine situations where these kinds of checks would not be thread safe.  But all that seems moot since you have race conditions between writer threads "updating" elements while a reader thread is scanning them.

Answer (score 2):

STL is not MT-safe. Please take a look at [Introductory-STL-tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563/An-Introductory-STL-tutorial) - specifically the "Multithreading Issues" chapter. In your case threads 2 and 3 can compete for the same vector element - so you need a mutex in each element.